# C# Property doesn't return the value I change at the set accessor

Tags: c#, properties

**The Property:**

```
public double TotalFee
{ 
    get { return totalfee; }
    set
    {
        if ((course == "C#") || (course == "c#")) { totalfee = 2000; }
        else { totalfee = 3000; }
    }
}
```

I have created a variable named *totalfee:* ' private double totalfee;' ,of which I didn't assign any value at the beginning and when i call the property at my program returns 0.
Even if I give a pre-value for *totalfee* it only returns that value without going to none of the conditions I've made.
The idea is that when the user inputs the course: c# it will return the value for the *totalfee* 2000;and if he inputs another course it will return the value for the *totalfee* 3000.  :/

Comment: Can you share more of your code? Like where you call the setter and getter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you don't need the private field at all. You can just put all the logic in the getter:

```
public double TotalFee
{ 
    get
    {
        if ((course == "C#") || (course == "c#")) { return 2000; }
        else { return 3000; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ,for your quick answer! It worked :)

Answer (score 1):

If TotalFee is not meant to be directly changeable, the code where you set the totalFee should be in the Course setter, not the TotalFee setter. For example:

```
public double TotalFee
{ 
    get { return totalfee; }
}

public string Course
{
    get { return course; }
    set
    {
        course = value;
        if ((course == "C#") || (course == "c#")) { totalfee = 2000; }
        else { totalfee = 3000; }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay thanks for the heads-up, I edited it

Comment: Thank you!  It's just that I was "obligated" to do that on my TotalFee property without creating a new one. But anyway lots of thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

When you first call a double without first assigning (setting) a value to it, its default value is zero. This is the reason why you see this value when you run your code.
Your program will only run through your "set" logic if you are setting the property value, for example `myclass.myproperty = 1`.

The solution for your case would be to simply put your logic on the get method, so when you access your TotalFee, the logic will kick in.